# Finding a diode's operation point (Q-point)

Tags: diodes, thevenin

I'm struggling with what should be a fairly simple excercise, I have to determine the diode's Q-point using the [load line method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_line_%28electronics%29) given the diode's characteristic curve, however if you look at the wikipedia entry, you would see that the method is described for a circuit consisting of a voltage source, a resistor and the diode connected in series.

So far I've used Thevenin's theorem to obtain a circuit for the load line analysis, the values of the equivalent circuit that I found are:

\$ V_{th} = 3.36 v \$

\$ R_{th} = 66.95 \Omega \$

But, if you look closely on the characteristic curve you'll see that the load line's cut-off point (3.36, 0) is NOT in the graph. So maybe my mistake is in finding the equivalent circuit or maybe that's not the correct way to approach the problem, so I wonder if the load line is calculated from the circuit or if it is chosen and then calculations are performed on the selected values.

Any help is truly apreciated.
[image: My Problem]

Comment: I think your \$R_{th}\$ is not correct. Can you post your calculation?

Comment: stevenvh is correct.  By inspection, the resistance (in ohms) "seen" by the diode is 50 || (45 || 500 + 45) < 50

Answer (score 4):

I agree with your value for \$V_{th}\$, but not with your \$R_{th}\$. You have 50 Ω between the two diode nodes, and then a parallel network, so the equivalent resistance can never be greater than 50 Ω. I found 31.66 Ω.

But that still means the point (3.36 V, 0 mA) is off the graph. Now you can calculate the line's equation, but that's not even necessary. If for 0 V you have 3.37 V/ 31.66 Ω = 10.6 mA, then moving halfway to the (3.37 V, 0 mA) point the line will drop to half its height, so (3.37/2 V, 10.6/2 mA) is also a point on the line, and that is on the graph, so you can draw the line between (0 V, 10.6 mA) and (1.68 V, 5.3 mA):

[image]

So the diode's operation point is at 625 mV, for a current of 8.8 mA.

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about lines is that you can predict where they're going pretty easily. If your ideal endpoint on the X axis is not on the graph, you can calculate another point that is on the graph. I am not checking to see if you calculated the Thevenin equivalents correctly.

The load line method involves drawing a line from the maximum current that the resistor could draw to the maximum voltage that could be across the diode. The intersection of the load line and the diode curve is the operating/quiescent point.

Option 1: Find the midpoint between the y-intercept and the x-intercept. This is really easy to find, since the midpoint is (x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2.

Option 2: Calculate the equation for the load line, and solve for a point on the x-axis. This is also fairly easy, just solve for the constants in the equation for a line: y = mx+b, and then solve the line equation at an intersection of a grid line (e.g. x=1.0, or 1.5, or 2.0.....)